# Unespected (frequent) freeze crash with Xubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, freeze, crash

two months ago I got a new Lenovo Thinkpad X11 gen 8, where I installed Xubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.

I'm experiencing frequent, apparently random, crashes: everithing frozen, crtl+alt F1, does not work, and no way I can force shotdown/restart. I just can brutely swicth of the computer by pressing the I/O button for 15 seconds.

So, where can I start to look? I guess I should attach some log file, but which exaclty?

If this is a known issue, how can I fix it?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon -s` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: This is not my case: my laptop has 2xRAM of swap and usually is doing apparently nothing special when freezing

Answer (score 1):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.
.